# OutOfMemoryError: Как сбросить размер буфера BufferedReader?

Tags: java

Нужно максимально быстро читать большие файлы. Для чтения используется BufferedReader в таком виде:

```java
String line, data="";
            int RAM = 1073741822; //1Gb
                 try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path), RAM)) {
                        while((line=br.readLine())!= null) {
                                data+=line;
                                }
                        br.close();
                        }
```

Один раз метод отрабатывает без проблем. Но на втором вызове возникает ошибка `OutOfMemoryError`. По всей видимости JVM или BufferedReader кэширует размер буфера невзирая на его закрытие... Существуют ли какие-то решения?

Comment: нужна альтернатива методу `Files.readAllBytes();` Он классно работает, но он может оказаться занят или переполненным. Его максимальный размер обусловленный JVM (?) 2Gb.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html

Comment: что же до BufferedReader - тут проблема не в закрытии и не в сбросе, а в том что сборщик мусора не успевает отрабатывать, и вообще большие объекты могут собираться отдельным алгоритмом

Comment: проще найти замену BufferedReader чем починить BufferedReader с таким буфером

Comment: Очень может быть, что сам BufferReader не виноват. Во-первых, очень плохо для памяти собирать строку операцией `+=`. Каждый такой вызов создает новый объект (!). Т.е. если файл большой то на последних итерациях цикла и у вас данные в памяти хранятся три раза: в BufferReader, в старом data и в новом data. Используйте StringBuilder. Во-вторых, что вы делаете дальше со строкой? Она у вас случайно не висит в памяти при повторном вызове BufferReader? Чтоб диагностировать проблему запустите программу о опцией создвать дамп памяти при OOME и посмотрите, где она _реально_ расходуется.

Comment: ну мне кажеться надо перейти на FileChanel и использовать byteBuffer,что бы  не нагружать memory. мы гоням  видеофайлв  имеено  через NIO

Comment: @PavelMayorov " сборщик мусора не успевает отрабатывать" перед тем как бросать OutOfMemoryError всегда делается полная сборка мусора. Так что или памяти реально не хватает, либо она фрагметрированна (см. коментарий про использование строк выше - это как раз на фрагментацию влияет)  и не удается выделить непрерывный кусок в 1гиг.

Comment: @Труфальдино не вижу как это поможет. Если из соображений производительности нужно читать буферизированно с таким большим буфером, то все равно память будет использована независимо от метода. Если же такой большой буфер не нужен, то и при использовании BufferedReader достаточно его уменьшить.

Comment: написано- освобождать  память  максимально быстро. Если перевести все в ByteBuffer ,  то проблем с обвобождением java memory быть не должно. Если автор  в памяти обрабатывает файл,  большой файл,  то здесь еще  важнее  рабоать за  пределами  java  memory

Comment: Если файл большой, то его надо разбить на части и читать по частям. Я думаю что `RandomFileAccess` не подойдет. Вообще идея не плохая, весь файл загружать в память. Если файл помещается в памяти, то проблем не должно быть.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA  `data+=data` - конкатенация данных к одной и той же переменной. На выходе она одна. Как только операция readLine() выполнена, переменная переопределена. Она по ходу ничего не возвращает (тут не принципиально). Проблема именно с размером буфера. JVM (теоретически) ограничена 2Gb, а по некоторым данным (с интернета) размер кучи в Windows максимум 1,6Gb. У меня возникает OutOfMemoryError при ~1,5Gb

Comment: Вы не поняли смысл моего комментария о конкатенации строк. Переменная data одна, но конкатенация строк работает на так, как, очевидно, вы себе представляете. Строки в java неизменные (immutable), а это значит, что нельзя модифицировать строку добавив к ней еще данных. При конкатенации всегда создается новый объект типа String и в него копируются данные из строк которые склеиваются. И этот объект создается до того как можно сохранить ссылку на него в переменную data. По-этому в процессе операции у вас в памяти практически те же данные хранятся два раза.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Да, действительно, я вас не правильно понял. Спасибо за доп. инфо. P.s. поправил вопрос чтоб не возникало путаницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jvm oracle, 32 разряда,2 ГБ java memory, GC  policy стандатная не парралельная. Исходный файл 1,5 ГБ. Обрабатывает два файла. Потом умирает.
Два файла по 1,5 GB jvm успевает обработать за один цикл GC. Можно поиграться с GC policy.

```
 File f = new File("c:\\work\\Camera1.zip"); // 1.5 Gg
    try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
    FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();) 
    {
    if ((int) fc.size() <= Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1) 
    {
    java.nio.ByteBuffer buffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate((int) fc.size());
    fc.read(buffer);
    buffer.flip();
    System.err.println(":= " +buffer.isDirect());
    buffer.clear();
    
    java.nio.ByteBuffer buffer2 = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate((int) 
    fc.size());
    fc.read(buffer2);
    buffer.flip();
    System.err.println("2:= " +buffer.capacity());
    buffer2.clear();
    }
```

}

В асинхронном режиме работает и не умирает. Правда диск начинает подвывать, но не умирает.

Comment: Определил размер буфера меньше 1Gb (1000Mb) и BufferedReader тоже работает и не умирает. Вопрос: `RandomAccessFile` работает быстрее чем `BufferedReader`?